# Is SQL Injection possible when <>"'%;() are removed?

Tags: java, sql, hibernate, jsp, sql-injection

I just stumbled upon some SQL code of a colleague (we have a "dont fix it, if it aint broke policy"), for a login process.
The name variable is delivered by an input field from a JSP.

```
//BAD CODING ALERT: DONT USE THIS CRAPPY CODE, YOU NAUGHTY COPY PASTERS!
Query q = em.createQuery("select object(u) from User as u where u.name = '" + name + "'");
```

With no sanitation at all on the `name` variable except of server side validating on some Illegal characters: `<>"'%;()` (mind that that is single and double quotes)

**Can this be exploited? And if yes, how so?**

If it wasnt for the single and double quotes, one could do something like: `blah' OR 'x'='x`

Comment: How would you handle a user with the name O'Reilly?

Comment: Obligatory XKCD link http://xkcd.com/327/

Comment: If em stands for EntityManager, that might imply there's a chance you're using JPA. It doesn't actually matter if you're using JPA or Hibernate directly, why on earth is he, then, concatenating a SQL sentence like that? Use the methods provided by `Query` instead, and let the framework manage the sanitization.

Comment: @Olaf O'Reilly is not allowed

Comment: @Terence: Oh, really? ;-)

Comment: security caveat - assume it can be hacked. and when you have something like prepared statements that is tested by 1,0000s why not use that? answer that. asking for a needle in a hay stack is tough but using the free work horse (prepared statements is straight forward in this case - pure jdbc). Helpful folk might not find it but no hacker is going to answer you here, who might have an exploit. What is the issue in changing this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answering my own question... it is safe, however not practical as allready stated by myself.

Before downvoting this, READ the question. Or give an exploit example otherwise.

Comment: Why do it this waty? Just askin for trouble. Whay do u do when jr dev copies pastes edits this code in future?

Comment: no. i up voted you, not cause I agree, but  like to encourage discussion.

Answer (score 2):

You should NEVER EVER create query by string concatenation. use `query.setParameter("paramName",paramValue);`

so it would be something like that

```
Query q = em.createQuery("select object(u) from User as u where u.name =:name");
q.setParameter("name", "O'Reilly")
```

no SQLInjections possible because of escaping values;

Comment: Very good refactoring, but look at my original question. I asked how the previous can (or perhaps cannot) be exploited. And do mind it is NOT ME, but my colleague.

Comment: I have never tried to add "OR 1=1" to hibernate query, but you can give it a try. SQL injection vulnerability depends not as much on returned results (worst case scenerio - DB dump or drop xD) returned by query, but on actions that are done with results set.
So yes, in your example you can always provide `u.name` as name - this will return all users from DB having name (name is not null). The question is, what are you doing with it later on. Maybe you mail returned user password to provided email, here all passwords - just a stupid example but possible.

Comment: Entering u.name (in the original post sql) will be treated as a string not a column